# AWS Cloudformation: Use existing SG Cidr Range, but different Port Number

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

So I have a Cloudformation template to make multiple security groups for several different RDS instances. Each different type of DB instance has a different port number like (1321 or 3309, etc.) but all have the same CidrIP range for the same service (Splunk) which exists in another Security group.

If I ever move my external service like SPlunk to a different Cidr block - I want to be able to update one place and not like 30 different security groups.

Any way to only pull IP range from an existing security group in Cloudformation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a cidr block from a security group resource. You can see the supported return values here 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#w2ab2c21c10d476c15

Instead, pass the service CIDR block as a parameter to your template, and reference it in the required security groups.

Updating the stack parameter at any time and cloudformation will update all the security groups as needed.